# Printing a conditional index value based on substring

Tags: python, list, substring

I feel like this is simple. I have a list that contains strings and want to print the index if it contains a certain word (triggerword). I'm able to get it to pull the index, but I'm having trouble printing the actual value of that index in the list.

```
 list = [' test', ' tests triggerword', ' test3', ' 12345']

 x = [list.index(i) for i in list if 'triggerword' in i]
 print(x)
 [1]
```

I want to print `tests triggerword`

Comment: Can you give an example of the contents of `list` and what you would expect the results of printing `l` to be? I'm not sure I'm following what's not working.

Comment: Yup, as @GAEfan mentioned. The indices you store in `x` will give you the position within `list` of the strings containing `'triggerword'`. You can either also store the strings themselves directly as in his example, or dereference the indices later by doing something like `for idx in x: print(list[idx])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
my_list = [' test', ' tests triggerword', ' test3', 'triggerword', ' 12345']

x = [[my_list.index(i), i] for i in my_list if 'triggerword' in i]

print(x)

>>> [[1, ' tests triggerword'], [3, 'triggerword']]
```

BTW, `list` should be reserved as a python function.  Not a good idea to use it as a variable.  So, I would change it to `my_list` or similar.  Otherwise, you can run into errors like:

```
print(list(list))
>>> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Yep thank you!! I made it 'list' in the question just for the sake of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index while walking the array, and then return a tuple of the index and the actual element. See below:

```
>>> L = [' test', ' tests triggerword', ' test3', ' 12345']
>>> [(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(L) if 'triggerword' in x]
[(1, ' tests triggerword')]
```